# Storyboard threading error

Tags: ios, crash, uistoryboard

Hi I keep getting threading errors. I have made a very simple storyboard that has two screens. The first has a button that leads to the second. When I run the app and click the button it crashes with a threading error. I haven't every written any of the code yet has only been working on the storyboards. If you could please advise what is causing it or a way for me to workout what is causing it as I am unable to understand the thread debug errors.

> 2013-10-10 20:18:54.249 Quote[851:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x017475e4 **exceptionPreprocess + 180
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014b68b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
>       2   UIKit                               0x0076c605 -[UIStoryboardPushSegue destinationContainmentContext] + 0
>       3   UIKit                               0x0075c9de -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 174
>       4   UIKit                               0x0075ca59 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 115
>       5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014c8874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
>       6   UIKit                               0x0022ac8c -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
>       7   UIKit                               0x0022ac18 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
>       8   UIKit                               0x003226d9 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
>       9   UIKit                               0x00322a9c -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
>       10  UIKit                               0x00321d4b -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
>       11  UIKit                               0x002680cd -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
>       12  UIKit                               0x00268d34 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1232
>       13  UIKit                               0x0023ca36 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
>       14  UIKit                               0x00226d9f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
>       15  CoreFoundation                      0x016d08af __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 15
>       16  CoreFoundation                      0x016d023b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
>       17  CoreFoundation                      0x016ed30e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
>       18  CoreFoundation                      0x016ecb33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
>       19  CoreFoundation                      0x016ec94b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
>       20  GraphicsServices                    0x036849d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
>       21  GraphicsServices                    0x036847fe GSEventRun + 104
>       22  UIKit                               0x0022994b UIApplicationMain + 1225
>       23  Quote                               0x0000217d main + 141
>       24  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d6f725 start + 0
>       25  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

Comment: I find it very unlikely to be a threading error. Could you at least publish the stacktrace?

Comment: It's almost impossible for anyone to offer advice without _the exact text_ of the crash message.

Comment: Okay, good. So that tells you what's going wrong: "Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController." What have you done to remedy that? Or, if you don't understand it, what have you done to learn what that means?

Answer (score 2):

"'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController."

That is your problem, Push Segues can only be used with a UINavigationController. To put your first view controller in a navigation controller, click on your first view controller then Editor > Embed > Navigation controller.